# Is an expression in normal form if terminates on normal order but not applicative?

Tags: lambda-calculus

Just wondering if something like this...

```
(λx. y)((λx. (x x))(λx. (x x)))
```

Would be considered to be in normal form since it terminates with y if done by normal order but does not terminate if done by applicative order

Comment: No, it's not in normal form, since it can be reduced under both evaluation strategies.

Comment: Thanks for confirming Anton.   You did mean to say "since it can't be reduced" right?

Comment: It *can* be reduced, since it's an application. You can find more details here http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/7704/39226

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression $(\lambda x.y \  (\lambda x.(x \  \ x) \  \lambda x.(x \ \  x)))$
is not in normal form because it can be further reduced using the β-rule.

Also, as you noted, **Applicative Order** is not a *normalising reduction strategy*. For the expression $(\lambda x.y \  (\lambda x.(x \  \ x) \  \lambda x.(x \ \  x)))$ it fails to find the normal form. This is because $(\lambda x.(x \  \ x) \  \lambda x.(x \ \  x))$ is a non-terminating argument, it has no normal form, then it will loop forever.

On the other side, **Normal Order** is a *normalising reduction strategy* because it will always find the normal form, if it exists of course. In fact this a practical consequence of the second Church-Rosser theorem. For the expression $(\lambda x.y \  (\lambda x.(x \  \ x) \  \lambda x.(x \ \  x)))$ it finds the normal form. In this case, since $\lambda x. y$ is a constant function, it will ignore its (non-terminating) argument.